# Magento2 How to get custom attribute and its value of a customer?

Tags: magento2, custom

I followed [this tutorial](https://maxyek.wordpress.com/2015/10/22/building-magento-2-extension-customergrid/comment-page-1/) to add a custom attribute to Customer.  Then in Controller LoginPost.php, I want to get the value of that attribute of a particular customer to do some checking. But I found it completely different from Magento 1.X to retrieve the value of a custom attribute.

Anyone can suggest some methods? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood my question. The problem I'm facing is how to retrieve the value of a custom attribute, NOT creating a custom attribute. Thanks.

Comment: Magento 1.X got $customerObj  = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);
$attr = $customerObj->getData('manager'); to retrieve the values. But in Magento2, I can't find the method to retrieve the values.

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate. Did you read the questions guys ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface` extends `\Magento\Framework\Api\CustomAttributesDataInterface` that have `getCustomAttribute()` method. You can use it to get custom attribute.
ex. for test:

```
$customerRepository = $objectManager
        ->get('Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface');
$customer = $customerRepository->getById(1);
$cattrValue = $customer->getCustomAttribute('my_custom_attribute');
```

Comment: @kandy.where can  i find implementation of getCustomAttribute.in customer model there is no implementation for this.

Comment: see \Magento\Framework\Api\AbstractExtensibleObject

Comment: $customer->getCustomAttribute('custom_id '); returns a Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValue Object ( [_data:protected] => Array ( [attribute_code] => custom_id [value] => a234 ) ) .Then how can I obtain the value 'a234' since I can't access to  \Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValue, so I have no ideas how to do that. Thanks

Comment: Finally, I found it by my guess. $customer->getCustomAttribute('custom_id ')->getValue();

Comment: Hi , Can you tell me how to save custom attribute..?

Comment: confirming $customer->getCustomAttribute('custom_id ')->getValue(); retrieves correct value as per @Ricky.C comment

Comment: To avoid Exception "Call to a member function getValue() on null"  `$value = $cattrValue ? $cattrValue->getValue() : null`