# fetch customer's custom attribute value on edit account page magento2

Tags: magento2, customer, custom

I have created some customer's custom attribute that I am using in registration process. And they are saving values properly.

Now I want show values of those custom attributes on 'customer/account/edit/' page on frontend in user's account. I am using

> $block->getCustomer()->getMyCustomAttributeCode();

but showing nothing even showing 500 error in console.

Is Magento2 following different way to fetch custom attribute value. Please help me in this.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91123/magento2-how-to-get-custom-attribute-and-its-value-of-a-customer

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91123/magento2-how-to-get-custom-attribute-and-its-value-of-a-customer

Comment: I tried with the same but not working, one more thing as per reference url is need to make change in block respective file ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento2 How to get custom attribute and its value of a customer?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91123/magento2-how-to-get-custom-attribute-and-its-value-of-a-customer)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

below code works for me in phtml file -

> $obm = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
>
> $customerSession = $obm->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
>
> if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
> echo $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
> echo $customerSession->getCustomer()->getMyAttributeCode();
>
> }